# Mathematica doesn't work with big numbers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I'm pretty new to mathematica, and for example, when I type: "= 56 * 22" it gives me the result, but when I try to to compute the product of bigger numbers, mathematica says that "no interpretations available". For example when I type: "= 32187382163872163652187352187352187538217538652138585287432185218735873512853872153875213875218735218765382175387521321398765219387621987369218763982176398721693872169387621938762193876219873621986398213 * 672136873621873621873682176387216387216487632876438274687326487326874632876487632874687564328763287648732684753287463287483274587325487532874587324576532765324476532645873268732687463287458325871587621876218763872168736218736218736876218763876432767632979328463".

Is there any limit in mathematica for the input size? What I'm doing wrong? I use mathematica 8. I was googling and I didn't find anybody experiencing something similar or any number limit for mathematica.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No problem, I got  21634326417697493573805006401985845117720224021210384523068656167350761828270014046766885702858652786651021978130653064579756148378689586252737747487737980051367494261305365927382060084634951971984882161420600076991893593586050114022722175983912053179344158556125590105099927782659832973781165169670298451669071411013677623799858944388806821502700293256588985414335563708278521331550789977787619091227270223079319330330095171308829141150388091363123223984843236619.

Comment: Just drop the leading `=` no reason to push the calculation to WolframAlpha

Comment: yes, of course, I have another tools for such big products, but I can't figure out, why my mathematica 8 can't compute this. I tried dropping the leading "=" but it doesn't do anything. Here is a screenshot: http://imageshack.us/f/4/wsmg.png/

Comment: ok got it, thanks anyway. The free form input was the problem. Dropping the "=" and evaluating it as "mathematica input" solved the problem :)